# How to force Cordova to emulate release apk, rather than debug apk?

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

```
cordova run --emulator
```

launches the debug apk, rather than the release apk.

A. I wonder why?
B. How can I solve this?

I tried to relocate the debug folder in another directory, in the hopes that this will cause the emulator to default to the release apk (which was the only one left in the apk directory) -- it didn't. The debug apk got launched from its original location as if the folder has not been moved. I'm curious about this too.

I went over the documentation and the various Q&A here and elsewhere, but I couldn't find a solution or explanation.

Comment: try cordova run --emulator --release

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova run --emulator --release
```

(as suggested in the first comment) solves the problem.